# Initiating Translation

Tags: blueprint, translation-manager

We are working on our blue print design and want to take translation strategy into picture. SO my question is :
I have Global Content layer, Translation layer, master website layer, regional website layer and then countries websites.Can it be possible to initiate Translation at Regional layer by Regional owners. Means instead of pushing translation from Global layer or pulling translation job at translation layer, translation can be triggered by Regional owners after their approval at regional layer and content from global layer get translated and pulled down to Translation layer then then to regional layer. I hope my question is in understandable form. Do we need to change our blueprint because of this scenario??

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be fine with it. The way translation generally works is that you need to specify "language pairs" for your publications. Something along the lines of

Language Pair "English -> French"
Source Publication "030 Regional English Content"
Target Publication "040 Regional French Content"

TM will read the content from the `source` publication, then localize the related components or pages in the `Target` publication. Obviously, the same publication can be a source for multiple language pairs, but cannot be the target for multiple languages (I think *technically* it can, but it doesn't make much logical sense).

Basically, the content source does not need to be the publication where the content is created, it can be a child publication of "Global Content", so I think your scenario will work.

Comment: As of around Web 8, Organizational Items could indeed be configured for translation where the same Publication could have different target languages set on Folders, Categories, or Structure Groups.

In discussions since, our architect wondered if we really needed this amount of granularity. Though no plans have been set to change this. In all the BluePrinting hierarchies I've seen it was always _one Publication per language_.